# extract text from image

Tags: java, image-processing

extracting text from image

```
public class Test1 {

    public static void main(String[] args)throws Exception {    
        BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(new File("D:\\Test2.jpg")); 
                 String s = new OCR().recognizeCharacters(image);
        System.out.println("RESULTS: \n"+ s);
}
}
```

in above code work fine but output is correct is only one image 
but when i giving other image they can not extract text from image please help me what can i do.

Comment: depends on image I guess. what is OCR?

Comment: Usually Ocr recognition comes with a lot of parameters. Literally hundreds of them for full text recognition or other OCR features, what do you use for this?

Comment: @Admit Optical Character Recognition. Basically you 'scan' a page, and you may be able to extract the text in it. But it's hard and long.

Comment: i am using third party API for extraction text from image (aspirse group) in  that ocr class can work only one image that they given other image can not work well

Comment: please tell me how can apply other images or why not output is correct

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you can use Aspire and aspose api for that .i can work fine